# to implement circuit breaker pattern, spring hystrix and retryable which one is better to use

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

I was looking for the difference between spring hystrix and retryable in spring boot microservices as both are used to implement circuit breaker pattern.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, a circuit breaker is a component does not retry an operation that it's going to fail anyway.

Spring boot's [@Retryable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/org/springframework/retry/annotation/Retryable.html) was not designed to work as a circuit breaker, but as an exponential-backoff retry mechanism.

Hystrix is a circuit breaker library, but unfortunately it's not longer maintained. You can use [Resilience4J](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j). It's inspired from Hystrix, but much better.